# How to set an attribute value at a determined position inside an Xelement using Linq to xml?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I need to add a new attribute to an xml node which has about 10 attributes. Using the following command adds the attribute at the end of the element's attribute list.

`*identityVerificationManagerServiceNode.SetAttributeValue("PresetID", "24761685-715F-40F3-8FDA-5C2E372A1186");*`

I don't want it to go to the end, I need it after an attribute which XName is "DefinitionID".
Is there a way to change the attributes order inside an element using Linq to XML?

Comment: You could use the `XElement.ReplaceAttributes` method.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering of attributes can be easily done with XLinq:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement xe1 = XElement.Parse(@"<root><some-element a = '1' c = '3' b = '2' d = '4' e = '5' g = '6' h = '7'/></root>");
            XElement xe2 = new XElement("root");
            foreach (XElement xe in xe1.Elements()){
                xe2.Add(new XElement(xe.Name.LocalName, xe.Attributes().Select(c => c).OrderBy(c => c.Name.LocalName)));
            }
            Console.Write("unordered-->\n");
            Console.Write(xe1.ToString());
            Console.Write("\n\nordered-->\n");
            Console.Write(xe2.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```